# OpenGL use Q and E characters to move camera GLFW libraries

Tags: c++, glfw, glm-math

I cannot figure out the correct commands to add onto this and make the Q and E commands move the camera straight up and down.  I have tried a number of things to no success.

```
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    float cameraSpeed = 2.5 * deltaTime;
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        cameraPos += cameraSpeed * cameraFront;
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        cameraPos -= cameraSpeed * cameraFront;
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        cameraPos -= glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraFront, cameraUp)) * cameraSpeed;
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        cameraPos += glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraFront, cameraUp)) * cameraSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Presumably it's the same thing as with W/S, but with `cameraUp` instead of `cameraFront`.

Comment: Is `cameraUp` perpendicular to `cameraFront`?

Answer (score 1):

If `cameraUp` is perpendicular to `cameraFront`:

```cpp
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_Q) == GLFW_PRESS)
    cameraPos -= cameraSpeed * cameraUp;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_E) == GLFW_PRESS)
    cameraPos += cameraSpeed * cameraUp;
```

If `cameraUp` is not (exactly) perpendicular to `cameraFront` you have to compute the normal vector on the plane defined by `cross(cameraFront, cameraUp)` and `cameraFront`:

```cpp
glm::vec3 lateral_vector = glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraFront, cameraUp));
glm::vec3 up_vector = glm::normalize(glm::cross(lateral_vector, cameraFront));

if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
    cameraPos -= cameraSpeed * cameraFront;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
    cameraPos += cameraSpeed * cameraFront;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
    cameraPos -= cameraSpeed * lateral_vector;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
    cameraPos += cameraSpeed * lateral_vector;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_Q) == GLFW_PRESS)
    cameraPos -= cameraSpeed * up_vector;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_E) == GLFW_PRESS)
    cameraPos += cameraSpeed * up_vector;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_Q) == GLFW_PRESS)
    gCameraPos -= cameraSpeed * gCameraUp * cameraOffset;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_E) == GLFW_PRESS)
    gCameraPos += cameraSpeed * gCameraUp * cameraOffset;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Thank you!